# Find $Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ to construct $95 \text{%}$ confidence interval. Why is it $1.96$?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

find the value of $Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ to construct a confidence interval with level $95\text{%}$.

The answer to this is $1.96$. But I'm having trouble seeing why. I was under the impression that you could look up $.9500$ in the normal distribution table and get the $Z$ value $2.575$, which would be the $Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$. Why is it $1.96$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ that you are talking about is called the critical value in hypothesis testing in stats. You can look up the table in Mario Triola Elementary Statistics book or calculate it using the area. $\alpha = 1 - .95 = .05$. Thus $Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ is the $z$ value such that the area to the right of it is $0.025$ and this is $1.96$.

Comment: just curious, how do i know when my z value is positive or negative? because when i look up .025 the only corresponding z value i get is -1.96

Comment: You are true. There are two of them $\pm 1.96$, but you only need the positive one so you can ignore the negative one.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have a question asking you to find $z_{\alpha/2}$, you’re being asked to find an $\alpha$ level’s $z$-score for a **two tailed test**. How can we do this?

- Step $1$: Note the $\alpha$ level given in the question, here as the confidence level is $95%$, we have $\alpha=0.05$.
- Step $2$: Now we have $\frac12(\alpha) =0.025$. Subtracting it from $0.5$, we have the value of $0.475$.
- Step $3$: Comparing the value obtained with that of the $z$- value table, we have $z=1.96$,

Comment: why do you subtract it from .5? and what does a "two tailed test" mean?

Comment: The area of the z curve to the right (or left) of the mean (equals zero) is 0.5. Note that the curve is symmetric about the mean. As we have $\alpha/2$, it means we are looking on both sides of the curve with an area of 0.05. This is the gist of the two-tailed test. Note that if it was only $\alpha$, we would have been looking on one side and thus your z value of 2.575 would have been correct. This scenario resembles the one-tailed test.

Comment: I think you may want to subtract from $1$ to give $0.975$ and then your tables will tell you $\Phi^{-1}(0.975) \approx 1.96$